# Can I use guess in this way?

Tags: adjuncts

I heard a lot that people use sentences like I like fruit, say, an apple, or he has, say, a thousand dollars. What about I get, guess, a hundred dogs.

Comment: No, I use it in a sense of approximately.

Comment: He is, **I guess**, two metres tall.

Comment: Then, Is say a special case?

Comment: When used to mean ***for example***, the single-word form ***say*** could be "short for" several alternatives, including both ***I would say*** and ***let us say***. But idiomatically there's no short form involving the word ***guess*** that can straddle both meanings - it's either ***I ['d, would] guess*** or ***Let's guess / suppose / assume***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to understand your question: you are asking whether you can use *guess* as a parenthetical on its own, like *say*, yes?

The answer is "no". I can't think of any other verbs that can be used in that way: I was considering "suppose"; but although it can be used without a subject (eg *Suppose we went that way*) I don't think it gets used in the middle of a clause like *say*.

***I** guess* is fine in that context. So are *I suppose*, *I think*, *I remember*, and many others .